# What's the  best open source game to learn from?

Tags: open-source

> This question has been preserved for historical reasons, but it is not
>   considered on-topic, so don't use it as an excuse to post something
>   similar.
>
> More info at https://stackoverflow.com/faq.

---

For me to read code and learn, not to play...

...of course ;-)

Answer (score 70):

[Quake](ftp://ftp.idsoftware.com/idstuff/source/) (1,2 and 3) and [DukeNukem 3D](http://www.3drealms.com/downloads.html#duke3d) source code is available under the GPL.

Comment: Although originally commercial, the fact that these games are now released under the GPL make them the best open source games. Ever. You can't compete with Quake. You can't compete with what it means.

Comment: Just a quick "legalese" comment: the source code of the "game engines" for these games is open source now. The graphics, maps, characters, story, etc. are still proprietary copyrighted items. If you want to play them, you have to either use the files provided with the shareware version or buy it :(

Comment: Agreed, but for learning games programming, these sources are invaluable!

Comment: Another thing you can learn from these is historic, how they managed to get it to work on the hardware of the day.

Comment: Although being good games this doesn't mean the code is readable and good to play with.
It's also heavily optimized, that will bring you some headaches in understanding the real inner workings.
Anyway, if you like the procedural approach in games you'll be pretty much satisfied with it.

Comment: Agreed, can't beat quake.
Try OpenArena for a fully free package, and ioquake3 for a somewhat modernized version

Answer (score 67):

If part of the reason for open-source code is for code to be reused and recycled as it evolves, then I think influence and legacy would be two large factors in this decision. On this basis, I would probably vote [Rogue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_(computer_game)) / [Hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hack_(video_game)) / [Nethack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nethack). It was one of the seminal influences behind the hack-and-slash dungeon-crawling genre, living on today in thriving communities that still play these old ASCII games, as well as having a significant influence on some of the most popular graphical games of all time, such as Diablo and Diablo 2.

Comment: Don't forget the Moria/Angband development tree.

Comment: And Nethack has a a lot of technology in the code.  UI abstraction layer, serialzation, domain specific data description language with a compiler, etc.

Comment: And remember the reason it's called NetHack is because it was one of the first programs written collaboratively over the net. It was so new that deserved a special distinction in the name!

Comment: I think you can put MUDs in that tree as well: multiplayer realtime Internet text adventure game. CircleMUD has very good documentation and I started with that a few years ago: http://www.circlemud.org/

Answer (score 46):

[Battle for Wesnoth](http://www.wesnoth.org/)

That said, you can devote some time reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_games

It also depends what exactly do you want to learn... For instance there is an annual competition for games written in [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org)

Answer (score 37):

What about OpenTransportTycoon? :) Come one people - that's got to be the best!

http://www.openttd.org FTW! ;)

Comment: the best ever, now only if they could create good API for programming your own bots.

Comment: ..They've come close with NoAI now.  oTTD is an interesting read, I've been able to learn a fair bit just by reading the oTTD source code.

Answer (score 31):

How about [FreeCiv](http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page)?

Comment: One problem I have with FreeCiv is it doesn't run smoothly on older hardware. Otherwise I love it.

Comment: I've got a really really old original Pentium running BSD that I run Freeciv on, it runs fine, except for the graphics in the client, the window is too large to fit on my older resolution monitor. So, i can't see the tabs on the bottom.

Comment: Try the trident tileset for older computers. Should work fine.

Answer (score 31):

Check out [Kenta Cho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenta_Cho)'s games: http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~cs8k-cyu/index_e.html. Most of them are written in D and use [Simple DirectMedia Layer](http://www.libsdl.org/).

They're a lot of fun and the source is extremely readable - a great showcase for the D language.

[Torus Trooper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_Trooper) screenshot:

[alt text http://images.macworld.com/images/legacy/images/content/torus.jpg](http://images.macworld.com/images/legacy/images/content/torus.jpg)

Comment: Whoa, +1 for neat games written in D!

Comment: Kenta Cho's games are awesome - the best probably being Gunroar or rRootage.

Answer (score 25):

There is a very good text based role playing game called 'make', you are on a quest to find hidden dependancies guarded by bearded sages and wrestle patches from them.

Answer (score 20):

[Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) is pretty awesome. See also its [entry at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocode).

Answer (score 16):

```
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . S . . . . .
. . * . . . . * . .
. . . . . . . . . *
. * . . . * . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . E . . . . . .
. . . . . * . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . 
. . . * . . . . . .
```

This one... the original Star Trek. PDP11 rulez! :)

Comment: I remember playing this at school on a dot-matrix console... right up there with a civil war program and some wierd mafioso program (that the name escapes me atm)

Comment: You can download a PDP-11 version of Empire, too! http://www.classicempire.com

Comment: @Christopher Klein: probably Syndicate

Answer (score 16):

[alt text http://sc2.sourceforge.net/screenshots/melee2.png](http://sc2.sourceforge.net/screenshots/melee2.png)

[Ur Quan Masters - Star Control 2 update](http://sc2.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Just wanted to say this is *excellent*. The feel of the space combat is spot on.

Comment: Excellent game.  This screenshot perhaps doesn't do it justice; Star Control II is often rated one of the best games ever (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Control_II#Accolades).

Answer (score 12):

I'd have to go with [GNU Chess](http://www.gnu.org/software/chess/).

If you're really interested in looking at the code.  From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Chess): "Version 5 was essentially a complete rewrite from scratch of GNU Chess to eliminate spaghetti code and replace antiquated data structures with more advanced computer chess implementation techniques."

Answer (score 11):

I can't believe [Hunt the Wumpus](http://www.atariarchives.org/bcc1/showpage.php?page=247) hasn't been mentioned.

Or [Star Trek](http://www3.sympatico.ca/maury/games/space/star_trek.html)?

Comment: My favorite implementation is "Be the Wumpus", which features audio ONLY.

Answer (score 10):

two words: Frozen Bubble.

Answer (score 9):

My personal favorite is [UFO Alien Invasion](http://ufoai.sourceforge.net/). I loved the original UFO and this is a really good clone.

Answer (score 8):

What? No one here likes [Tux Racer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tux_Racer)?

I just LOVE that game!!! It's fast paced and can run on almost any decent modern computer (no need for expensive video cards). And it runs on Windows, too!! Furthermore, it demonstrates that "penguins can fly" (and even surpass speed of sound :P)

Comment: It's been my favorite one for a while too!

Comment: I won't vote you down, but I have never been impressed with TuxRacer.

Comment: Tux Racer was neat back when I first got MesaGL working, but I can't help seeing it as a perfect example of how linux is a second-class citizen in the gaming world.

Answer (score 8):

No question in my mind, GL Tron.  How can you not love it?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLtron

Comment: Because it's kind of boring. It's like Minesweeper for Tron fans. Never the less, I will not vote it down.

Comment: Against the computer it's boring indeed.  But it's a lot of fun against real people.

Answer (score 7):

[Jagged Alliance 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_Alliance_2)

Its source code was released in 2004 (I think) and since then it has been improved very much by the mod community. The mod goes under the name [JA2 v1.13](http://ja2v113.pbwiki.com/) and the community resides at [Bear's Pit](http://www.ja-galaxy-forum.com/).

P.S. For reading and learning from the code, this might not be the best project. It's old C code with many functions spanning hundreds of lines. Unless you want to learn [how to work with legacy code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052), playing it is more fun. ;)

Comment: Jagged Alliance 2 would be a good start if you want to practice your review skills.

Answer (score 5):

well....

If you'r into Flight simulators the definitively check out Free Space  just can

http://scp.indiegames.us/

There are also tons of mods...  a very nice one is on the battlestar gallactica universe where you actually fly the viper mark VII

http://www.game-warden.com/bsg/

have fun...  errr, of course, where's my head...

happy code reading  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If your intent is to see how a game works and are willing to spend a small amount of money to see it, I highly recommend the [Torque Gaming Engine](http://www.garagegames.com/products/111) from [GarageGames](http://www.garagegames.com).  For $150 you get the entire engine source code of a AAA game title (Tribes 2).  The content was ripped so you aren't buying Tribes 2, but content is easy to replace.  Compared to the cost of other comparable engines, Torque is an amazing bargain.  And if you ever decide to produce a game, you can do so without overbearing licensing restrictions.

EDIT: I know its not Open Source, but for your purpose of learning code it should qualify.  The engine is coded in C++ and there is a script layer that is similar in syntax to C#/Java.

Answer (score 5):

[alt text http://www.classicempire.com/emlogo.jpg](http://www.classicempire.com/emlogo.jpg)

Empire, the Wargame of the Century, naturally. You can download it from [classicempire.com](http://www.classicempire.com). Empire has been flunking out students and wrecking marriages since the 1970's.

Comment: anything that can get this has got to be good: http://www.classicempire.com/epyx.html

Answer (score 5):

[Sauerbraten](http://sauerbraten.org/) 
Very nice FPS

Comment: also the code is extremely elegant and clean, a master piece of software development.

Comment: The code follows a certain philosophy and really does well in being minimalistic. It's actually a great piece of code if you wish to see how clean and elegantly optimizations can be done.

Answer (score 4):

[Wormux](http://wormux.org/wiki/en/index.php) really has a fantastic architechture. i'm a professional game developer and i think that these guys really might be too. the quality of the work smells of years of game dev experience.

Answer (score 4):

It's got to be either [Rogue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_(computer_game))

[Rogue Screenshot http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/af/Rogue_Unix_Screenshot_CAR.PNG](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/af/Rogue_Unix_Screenshot_CAR.PNG)

or [Empire](http://empireclassic.com/)  I've invested (lost) so much time in both of those.

Answer (score 4):

I've spent many hours playing [FreeCol](http://www.freecol.org) (a clone of Sid Meier's Colonization).

I mean "studying the source code of FreeCol".

Answer (score 4):

Quite recently a few of the games from the Humble Indie Bundle went open source and are probably pretty interesting for people to look into. Gish, Lugaru, and Penumbra were all opened.

http://www.wolfire.com/humble

Answer (score 3):

[Dopewars](http://dopewars.sourceforge.net/) is fun to play on the internet or on a LAN with friends. And it runs on Windows, OSX, Linux, iPhone and there is an adaptation on Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what platform you're going for, the XNA guys have a few "starter kits" of ready to build projects, the code is available, but it's not explicitly open source:

http://creators.xna.com/education/starterkits/

Answer (score 3):

So many games, so little time.

Answer (score 2):

[Warsow](http://www.warsow.net/?page=home), obviously.
It's a FPS, technically advanced as Quake 3, open source, with nicely documented code and a great community.

Comment: That's because it uses Quake 3 code base.

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe, nobody mentioned [Armagetron Advanced](http://www.armagetronad.net) yet!

For fans of the movie [Tron](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084827/), this is a nice way to waste some time online with other players worldwide.

Answer (score 2):

Duke3D released their source code. That's the best game ever.
[Source code is number 15 under duke3d](http://www.3drealms.com/downloads.html)

Answer (score 2):

A classic: [Crowther/Woods Adventure](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs/advent.w.gz) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No shout outs to [Angband](http://rephial.org/) yet? It went under new "ownership" in March of this year and is still the most addictive fantasty/dungeon style game I've seen. Source is readily available and it is pretty slick to see how a program can still be heavily active after its initial release back in 1993, or even later, if memory serves on its lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

No one mentioned [freedroidrpg](http://freedroid.sourceforge.net/) yet.

Answer (score 2):

Freespace 2 source code. It is based off of the original Volition Freespace 2 (released as open source). This is production (and thus "battle tested") code and will give you a good look at how shipping titles look (with all of the warts).

You can gain access to the FS2_open source through SVN here:

http://scp.indiegames.us/links.php

Answer (score 2):

I've spent more time with [Glubulation 2](http://globulation2.org/wiki/Main_Page) Than any other open source game.  Its an innovative and fresh variation on the RTS genre.

Answer (score 2):

[Tremulous](http://tremulous.net/) is a good multiplayer-game.

Answer (score 2):

[Hedgewars](http://hedgewars.org/) it's fun, runs smoothly, has nice graphics and everyone who liked Worms World Party will enjoy it.

```
  To compile and install you need:

  Qt >= 4.4
  FreePascal >= 2.2.0
  SDL >= 1.2.5
  SDL_net >= 1.2.5
  SDL_mixer >= 1.2
  SDL_image >= 1.2
  SDL_ttf >= 2.0
  CMake >= 2.6.0
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clearly has nothing to do with Worms.

Answer (score 1):

And I will add a console-game: [Meteora Evolution](http://meteora.lo2k.net/). It is a homebrew-game for the Nintendo DS and Open-Source.

Answer (score 1):

Gnu-Backgammon.

Answer (score 1):

Torcs, the Open Racing Simulator
http://torcs.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it counts as "open-source", but I loved QBasic Gorilla.Bas *grin* I used to edit it to make all buildings disappear when the banana hits the sun; then it's a Banana Free-For-All! xD

I also took the liberty to rename the game QBrian Gorilla to make fun of a friend of mine... Lame, I know, but hey, I was 14. Haha..

QBasic was the first programming language I got into, before later moving on to VB, and then ASP, PHP and VB.Net. Ah, nostalgia... =)

Answer (score 1):

Open Arena, the best of Quake 3 engine, entirely open-source.

Answer (score 1):

Completely surprised that [FreeCiv](http://freeciv.wikia.com) didn't get a mention yet. It is truly the best online multiplayer game out there. And I have played it for **hours**.

As for compiling, you can pick between the SDL client and the GTK client.

Comment: FreeCiv is currently the 5th most popular answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Distributed by Microsoft [MechCommander 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MechCommander_2) (good mech game).

Answer (score 1):

**[TeeWorlds](http://www.teeworlds.com/)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do unintentional source releases count?  If so, Half-Life 2 and EVE (though it was only the client code)

Comment: No, because they are not open-source

Comment: More precisely: they are illegal (to obtain and own).

Answer (score 0):

Global Thermonuclear War
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOPR)
or, tic tac toe

Comment: Hey, it isn't open source, he had to hack into their servers to play it.. :P

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a very quick C#.NET implementation of the classic Balderdash, check out the Digger source here:

http://www.lutzroeder.com/silverlight/

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly [AssaultCube](http://assault.cubers.net) ;) a fast and fun first-person-shooter that comes as a 40mb package.

[alt text http://assault.cubers.net/pics/main_actioncube.jpg](http://assault.cubers.net/pics/main_actioncube.jpg)

Written in messy C++ using SDL, OpenGL and OpenAL :P

Answer (score 0):

The MMORPG [Ryzom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryzom) was open sourced a few days ago ([blog post](http://dev.ryzom.com/news/13)).

While I'm not that well versed in game programming, paroneayea's [comment](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/c0ja2/breakthrough_for_free_software_gamingryzom/c0phtvr) on reddit makes me think it's worth a look:

> It's hard to understate how big of a release this is. The volume of assets here, the size of the codebase.. The fact that anyone can run their own MMORPG server, or contribute back useful assets to make it into the main server!
>
> Honestly I don't think I've been this excited about the freeing of a project since Blender was released as free and open source software nearly a decade ago.

[Source code](http://dev.ryzom.com/) - [Media assets](http://media.ryzom.com/)

Answer (score 0):

GNU Chess is the best. but game play wise people prefer Warsaw first person shooter game.

Answer (score 0):

Ubran terror is a great counter strike like game. http://www.urbanterror.info/news/home/

Answer (score 0):

Megaroids on the Atari ST. Was the demo application for the Megamax C compiler. Played it in Midres (640x200x4colors). Simple game that have this "one more" spirit.

Answer (score 0):

I played a lot myself at [Chromium](http://www.reptilelabour.com/software/chromium/). Back in 2005 it was ship with Mandrake distribution. All my no-I-will-never-use-Linux-but-only-consider-Windows friends where amazed by its **quality, beauty and fast pace style**.

[image: Chromium screenshot. A must according to me.]